# How do I calculate a power function by constructing a list with k elements, all being n, and then using the function product

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, product

I have succeeded with one method:

```
power1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
power1 n k | k < 0 = error "power not defined for negative exponent"
           | otherwise = product (replicate (fromInteger k) n)
```

But how do you do it with a list comprehension inside a function? I have tried to solve it for hours but I can't quite comprehend it.

```
power1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
power1 n k=product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with list comprehensions:

```
power1 n k = product [n | _ <- [1 .. k]]
```

Note though, that both this way and the one you wrote are not very efficient.

Comment: Thank you , it worked. It was much less complicated than I thought. How would you write it more efficiently? Maybe like this? :                                              power :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
     power n k | k < 0 = error "power: negative argument"
     power n 0 = 1
     power n k = n * power n (k-1)

Comment: Look at how `^` is [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E) in `base`.

Comment: @EL- There are better algorithms around. E.g. you can exploit `pow a (2*n) = pow (a*a) n` and `pow a (2*n+1) = a * pow (a*a) n` to obtain an algorithm that only performs `log n` operations instead of `n`. For large `n`, this is much more efficient.